# Selecionar opção dentro do c:forEach | JSP - JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, vraptor, jstl

Boa Noite,

Preciso de ajuda com um código JSTL. Preciso selecionar uma opção listada por um c:forEach e mandar para meu Contoller. Esse dados vem do banco de dados.

Para entender melhor a logica, eu tenho no banco salvo vários tipos de peças (no sistema chamo de grupoPeca) como parafuso, porca e arruela. Quero salvar um novo código de uma peça nova que chegou, então eu busco um tipo de peça (grupoPeca) na qual ele pertence. Seleciono o tipo da peça e salvo junto com o código novo. Um código tem somente um grupoPeca e um grupoPeca pode ter vários códigos.

Esse é meu controller que envia os dados para a pagina JSP

```
    todasGrupoPeca = CRUDBestRoute.buscarTodos(GrupoPeca.class);
    result.include("grupoPeca", todasGrupoPeca);
```

Esse é meu código que faz o loop na tela dos dados vindo do banco

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="descricao" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Descrição</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label class="mr-sm-2 sr-only" for="descricao">Preference</label>

                        <select name="descricao">
                            <option  selected="selected" >Selecione a descrição</option>
                            <c:forEach var="todasGrupoPeca" items="${grupoPeca}">
                                <option selected="selected" value="${p.grupoPeca}">
                                    <c:out value="${todasGrupoPeca.descricao}" />
                                </option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Após eu selecionar a opção desejada na pagina, quero salvar essa informação em uma variável para que eu possa salvar no banco com o codigo novo, tenho o seguinte código

```
    public static Peca p = new Peca();  
    public void adicionarPeca() {       
        System.out.println("Chamou o adicionar peca");
        System.out.println(p.getGrupoPeca());           
    }
```

O Peca é minha entidade, onde quero armazenar o que eu selecionei para enfim salvar no banco, abaixo minha entidade Peca

```
@Entity
public class Peca {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idPeca")
private int idPeca;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String codigo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "grupoPeca")
private GrupoPeca grupoPeca;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "celula")
private Celula celula;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "prateleira")
private Prateleira prateleira;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idPonto")
private Ponto ponto;



public Ponto getPonto() {
    return ponto;
}

public void setPonto(Ponto ponto) {
    this.ponto = ponto;
}

public Celula getCelula() {
    return celula;
}

public void setCelula(Celula celula) {
    this.celula = celula;
}

public Prateleira getPrateleira() {
    return prateleira;
}

public void setPrateleira(Prateleira prateleira) {
    this.prateleira = prateleira;
}

public GrupoPeca getGrupoPeca() {
    return grupoPeca;
}

public void setGrupoPeca(GrupoPeca grupoPeca) {
    this.grupoPeca = grupoPeca;
}

public int getIdPeca() {
    return idPeca;
}

public void setIdPeca(int idPeca) {
    this.idPeca = idPeca;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
```

A entidade Peca tem varios atributos codigo, grupoPeca, prateleira, celula e ponto. Tirando o código as demais informações vem listadas do banco para eu escolher a opção desejada.

Tenho tentando fazer dessa maneira que mostrei acima com bases nas minhas pesquisas, se puderem me ajudar a fazer funcionar esse código ou sugerir e mostrar uma maneira para que eu consiga selecionar as informações.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa Noite, resolvido da seguinte maneira.

JSP

```
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Descrição</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label class="mr-sm-2 sr-only" for="descricao">Preference</label>

                        <select class="form-control" name="idGrupoPeca" required>
                            <option value="">Selecione a descrição</option>
                            <c:forEach var="todasGrupoPeca" items="${grupoPeca}">
                                <option value="${todasGrupoPeca.idGrupoPeca}"
                                    <c:out value="${todasGrupoPeca.descricao}"> </c:out>>
                                    ${todasGrupoPeca.descricao}
                                </option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller que recebe o id da opção selecionada

```
public void adicionarPeca(String codigo, int idGrupoPeca, int idPrateleira, int idCelula) {
    System.out.println("Chamou o adicionar peca");

    System.out.printf("Grupo Peça -->" + idGrupoPeca);


}
```